# How can I allow users to post on others' profiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller

I have Users which have many Microposts. Microposts belong to a user. Right now only the user can post on his/her profile. How can I allow everyone to post there. I've run a migration that added the column "sender_id" to the Micropost table but I can't seem to figure out how to get this working with the sender_id. I'm new to rails thanks for reading.

Micropost create controller:

```
@user = User.find(73) #change so it posts to the user page im on
@micropost = @user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
@micropost.sender_id = current_user.id
if @micropost.save
  flash[:success] = "Music Posted!"
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Micropost Form:

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: "send a message" %>
  </div>
    <%= f.submit "Share", class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

In the Microposts table I want User_id to be the person with the profile and Sender_id to be the user that posts on the other's profile.

Solution was to added hidden_field_tag to the micropost form to get the user_id param set and then @user = User.find(params[:user_id])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your code to this:

```
@user = User.find(73) #change so it posts to the user page im on
@micropost = @user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
@micropost.sender = current_user # or whatever indicates your current user
if @micropost.save
  flash[:success] = "Music Posted!"
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Comment: That depends on the routing you use. If you have something like /users/:user_id/microposts then instead of "73" you can put `params[:user_id]`. You should check what do the params variable contain when executing the action to find out if you can already retrieve this info.

Comment: @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) returned "can't find user w/o an ID". I thought it would work. Is it because since the post isnt created yet user_id is nil for the post?

Comment: Are you sure that it is `users/:user_id` and not `users/:id` ? Run `rake routes` and see what is the url format for the page you are actually viewing.

Comment: sorry /users/:id(.:format) thats on the profile page User#show

Comment: Ok, so you can find the user via the params[:id]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29160/discussion-between-ayounesi-and-grotori)